# erlang regular expression is too large

Tags: regex, erlang, pcre

I've got `error:{badmatch,{error,{"regular expression is too large",29899}}}` while using large regular expression in erlang. This is concatenated expression, but I really need it because it is much more effective, than iterating throw several regexps.

I've read there http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt in "SIZE AND OTHER LIMITATIONS" section that PCRE can be compiled with bigger linkage size to process regular expressions that are truly enormous.

Is there any way to do it with erlang?

I've installed the latest stable version 17.1 from homebrew.

Comment: how do you get this error message? I have filtered the source code, and can't find a module that can issue this message.

Comment: `[H | T] = [ "\d+ abc" || _ <- lists:seq(1,10000)].`  

`SuperRegexp = lists:foldl(fun(R, SR) -> SR ++ "|" ++ R end, H, T).`  

`re:compile(SuperRegexp).`  

`{error,{"regular expression is too large",69999}}`

Comment: OK, the re:compile/1 is part of the beam library, not the re module (I didn't know that exists) and the check seems to be done in this library - at least the message is in the library file. There are no flag to modify the limit wen you start erl, so I am afraid that there is no simple way to make it work.

Comment: I've found that re2 library (https://github.com/tuncer/re2) doesn't have such strict restrictions. It also has max_mem option, which allows to use really enormous regexp. So, my problem is solved. Thx

Comment: Good to know, you should put it as an answer and mark it solved if anyone else try to solve the same issue.

Comment: A regex that large will probably have *nasty* performance implications. Just as a general recommendation, try to find another way to parse the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

RE2 library (github.com/tuncer/re2) doesn't have such strict restrictions. It also has max_mem option, which allows to use really enormous regexp